# Crash in string initializer in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, crash, initialization

I am suddenly seeing a change in behavior in code that hasn't changed.  Code *has* changed elsewhere, but I don't see how they're related.  Maybe someone here can.

So, here's the code that's been working just fine during many weeks of development:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int wordcount = 0;

    // here's some dummy data
    string words[] = {
        "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"
    };
```

When I say "work" I mean everything gets initialized fine, and the rest of main executes just fine.

The file containing `main` includes, among other things, a file `BinaryTree.h`, which defines a template class.

A small part of this method, the end, looks like this:

```
debugPrintf1("\nAfter rotation: to the %s\n", (childDir == LEFT ? "left" : "right"));
dumpTree(getRoot());

// Return the new root of this subtree
return wNode[PARENT];
}
```

This also has compiled and run just fine during weeks of development.  When I add one line, like so:

```
debugPrintf1("\nAfter rotation: to the %s\n", (childDir == LEFT ? "left" : "right"));
dumpTree(getRoot());
debugPrintf("=======================\n");  //  <-- added line 

// Return the new root of this subtree
return wNode[PARENT];
}
```

I get a crash in main.

FYI:  debugPrintf and debugPrintf1 are defined thus:

```
#define debugPrintf(x) printf(x)
#define debugPrintf1(x, y) printf(x, y)
```

Some environment details:

- Xcode 5.1
- Mac OS 10.8.5
- clang++ Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)

And the crash details.  The crash happens during the initialization of `words[]` here:

```
template <class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Allocator>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>::basic_string(const value_type* __s)
{
    _LIBCPP_ASSERT(__s != nullptr, "basic_string(const char*) detected nullptr");
    __init(__s, traits_type::length(__s));  // <-- CRASH IS ON THIS STATEMENT
#if _LIBCPP_DEBUG_LEVEL >= 2
    __get_db()->__insert_c(this);
#endif
}
```

in the `string` include file.  The debugger in Xcode indicates the line where the crash occurs as indicated above.

For those who like to dig really deep, here's the assembly code for the crash site:

```
0x1000016b7:  jmpq   0x1000016bc               ; main + 204 [inlined] basic_string + 55 at main.cpp:28
main + 149 at main.cpp:28
0x1000016bc:  movq   -0x410(%rbp), %rdi  ; CRASH IS ON THIS INSTRUCTION
0x1000016c3:  movq   -0x418(%rbp), %rsi
0x1000016ca:  movq   -0x420(%rbp), %rdx
```

And not to leave out the relevant registers:

```
rdi unsigned long   0x0000000000000002  
rbp unsigned long   0x00007fff5fbff9b0  
rsp unsigned long   0x00007fff5fbff3e0
```

I'm way out of my depth here. My gut tells me it's a bug, but there might be something more subtle going on than I can detect.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

EDIT:  I changed the code from `debugPrintf`s to this:

```
cerr << "\nAfter rotation: to the %s " << (childDir == LEFT ? "left" : "right") << endl;
dumpTree(getRoot());
cerr << "=======================\n" << endl;
```

and *that* ran fine... but *WHY?!?!?!?*

Comment: Have you included cstdio?

Comment: Not explicitly, but running the source through the preprocessor shows that `/usr/include/stdio.h` is being included by way of `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/cstdio` by way of *many* levels of includes, from an include of `<memory>` in my source file.

Comment: Right, assuming you're in a debugger somewhere, can you dereference mem location `0x7fff5fbff5a0` (`-0x410(%rbp)`)? And can you show more of the assembly code (a little before and a fair chunk after). It looks like it's a loop copying the string addresses.

Comment: I am embarrassed and annoyed to report that, after replacing the stream I/O code I tried, which ran with no issues, with the debugPrintf macro calls that I had there initially, I'm no longer getting a crash. I'm not 100% sure that I didn't change something else in the process, but I'm *pretty* sure.  If I can get it to fail again, I'll post the results.

Comment: And the saga continues... I found a zip file a created as the crash was occurring.  I created a new Xcode project from it, but the crash doesn't happen.  I'll try patching my existing project with files from the zip file and see if it happens again.  *Curse you Heisenbugs!* ;)

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue? I am experiencing something similar. I found this page on the microsoft support page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813810 I know we are both using Macs, but it seems like the issue could be the thread-safeness of the standard library itself. Is your program multi-threaded?

Comment: Not multi-threaded... at least, _I_ didn't create any threads.  And the problem just went away.  Whenever I tried to restore the project to state where I (thought) the problem showed up, the problem wasn't there. I looked at the MSDN support page, which did say the problem happened on multi-processor machines (which mine is).  It could be related, but I don't think I'll ever know how.  Wish I could be more help.